# How do I supress false 'Java version is out of date message' when running projects in Netbeans

Tags: java-8, netbeans-8

I use the Netbeans 8.2 IDE to design and run a desktop application written in Java FXML. The current Java RTE is 1.8.0_261. The OS is Windows 10. When I compile the project and attempt to run it at project level (`Run > Run Main Project`) a Java Update Project dialog is displayed with the message

> Your Java version is out of date

There are three prompts in the dialog,

> Update (Recommended) Block and Later

The first time the popup was displayed I selected `Update`. Then I closed NB, reopened it and tried to run the project again. The same dialog appeared. I selected the `Update` prompt again, but all this returned was a new popup saying

> You already have the latest Java  version on this platform.

To investigate the issue I opened the Java console via the Windows control panel. In the Security level for applications radio button set to `High`. I also notice an Exception Site List, which should not be of concern to me as I am only developing a desktop application.

How can I stop this happening and go back to `Run > Run Main Project` without these impediments?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. In Netbeans > Project Properties > Run I discovered that Netbeans had unilaterally changed the property

> Run: Standalone

to

> Run: as Web Start

I shall report this as a Netbeans bug as I cannot find any explanation for this behavior.